# handling Rest Api in Codeigniter 3.1.4

Tags: codeigniter

does the new codeigniter 3.1.4 version have any new features of handling rest api services.
can anyone share a documentation or example for the same for handling jWT tokens ?

Answer (score 0):

By default in codeigniter, I dont think so. but you can use Rest Client library as I mentioned below URL

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient